# Отличие кодировки windows-1251 от utf-8

Tags: html, кодировка

Чем отличается и когда и где лучше применять один или другой:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: Победа utf-8 -- неизбежна!!!

Comment: Это ясно, но сейчас, чтобы браузеры по умолчанию настроены на windows-1251 (((

Comment: смотря под какой ОС вы сидите ;)

Comment: убунту. написал для себя страничку, закодировал в utf-8. Все браузеры вместо русских букв выдали кракозябры, пока я их не заставил определять Юникод. Вот так.

Comment: если не лазил ручками в настройки то в linux и ubuntu в частности браузер по умолчанию выставляет кодировку локали (к примеру у меня utf8) проблеммы наблюдаются только на тех страницах где или не указана локаль или указана неверно (К примеру в заголовке utf8 а сама страница в win1251)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разница в том, что на UTF-8 - два байта, а на windows-1251 - один байт. Поэтому текст в Юникоде больше места занимает. А вообще при прочих равных лучше всегда использовать UTF-8 это сильно облегчает разработку под разные языки.

Comment: Все ascii символы в utf-8 занимают 1 байт остальные от 2-х до 6 (реально до 4-х)

UTF позволяет использовать **любые** символы (хоть китайские), а cp-1251 только ascii, кириллицу и еще 62 (?) всяких разных.

Comment: Немного оффтоп, но что-то вспомнилось, как я прифигел в свое время от того, что utf-8 и unicode - 2 разные кодировки)

Comment: Тогда надо еще вспомнить UTF-16, которую значительно чаще путают с Unicode

Comment: А может вспомнить и другие кодировки unicod'а? До кучи?

Comment: Тогда не забывайте еще, что UTF-16 бывает BE и LE, а UTF-8 бывает with BOM и without BOM :P

Comment: @Sh4dow: UTF-8 и Unicode — разные сущности, примерно как «пассажирский поезд» и «железнодорожный транспорт».
Как уже было отмечено, Microsoft использует для UTF-16 в своих программах название «Unicode», но Microsoft не уполномочен давать *определение,* что такое Unicode.